# Access methods of generic type in generic class

Tags: java, generics

In Java I construct a generic class with a String type as parameter. Inside the class, I'd like to access methods of the String type. But I am given an error cannot resolve symbol -- Anyone see the problem with this:

```
public final class App
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyClass<String> myClass = new MyClass<String>("some string");
  }
}

public class MyClass<T> {
  public MyClass(T someString) {
    String someSubString = someString.substring(2,3);
  }
}
```

This is an update:
Really I was using String as a placeholder -- Really what I'd like to do is:

```
public final class App
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyClass<SpecificType2> myClass = new MyClass<SpecificType2>();
  }
}

public class GeneralType {
    public methodOfSpecificType() {...}
}

public class SpecificType1 extends GeneralType {
    @Override
    public methodOfSpecificType() {...}
}

public class SpecificType2 extends GeneralType {
    @Override
    public methodOfSpecificType() {...}
}

public class MyClass<T> {
  public MyClass(T specificType) {
    specificType.methodOfSpecificType();
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen for a `MyClass<Integer>`?

Comment: You didn't "construct" the class with a String type, you constructed it with a generic type T.  If you want it to only work with String then there's no need to make it generic.

Comment: Though I think I figured out a way -- Instead of using a generic, specify the constructor argument as the general class, passing in the specific instances as needed

Comment: @AsafEbgi have you found an answer for this ?

Answer (score 3):

All the compiler knows by your example, is that `T` is an `Object`. `substring(int,int)` is not a method that belongs to the `Object` class so it can not guarantee that `substring` will exist, therefore it fails to compile.

If you want to be able to access `substring` here, then generics is really not for this solution. You should just have `T` as a `String`. You only use generics when you have need for *generic functionality*.

**Extra Reading**

- Have a read of this guide for [Why to use Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the parameter can be one of a pre-established set of objects, you can check the instance type during runtime using `instanceof`, then cast it, and use it:

```
if (specificType instanceof GeneralType) {
    GeneralType generalType = (GeneralType) specificType;
    generalType.methodOfSpecificType();
}
```

That should work.
However, you will end up implementing a different case for each type, so perhaps you should consider if using generics is the correct approach for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you always will receive a string in your constructor you must declare the parameter as a string:

```
public class MyClass<T> {
  public MyClass(String someString) {
    String someSubString = someString.substring(2,3);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a generic class in order to code a behavior that is supposed to be the same for every kind of base type you will use it for.

For example, if you write a container like `List<T>`, which has methods for adding, removing etc, it's supposed to work the same for `List<String>` or `List<Integer>` or `List<SomeUserClassIDontKnowAbout>`.

If the class behavior you are coding for is suitable for working only on one type of object, such as Strings, then it is not suitable to write it as generic, as it is specific, not generic. (Of course, it can be for a bounded generic type, but let's not go there at the moment).

If you have some methods that are supposed to work on specific types (such as accepting a String and parsing it into something else), it is OK to do so, but then you have to declare it with the specific type, not with your generic type variable (`T` etc.).

If you find that all your methods are specific and not generic, and you end up with the type variable only in the class header, then you are writing a specific class, not a generic one. No need to declare it as generic.