# How do I retrieve the data inside an object I receive by argument in Java?

Tags: java, object, instance-variables

I am attempting to build a Priority Queue by modifying my previously implemented Queue that accepts generics. I create a class called Priority Queue (which accepts generics) that extends my Queue class (which accepts generics). The last class is the prime focus, Queue< T >. I push a customer in my tests, and when I receive that customer in my push method of Queue , I want to use it to compare its priority to another customer's priority in my Queue. Any suggestions on approaching this will be helpful, but my question is, how do I access the 3 fields of my object customer ( or val in push) from inside Queue ?

I have a test class that tests if my comparators work. I also have set up a test cases so that I can ensure that my priority queue works when I implement it.

My class for testing if my comparators work and if my Priority Queue works when implemented:

```
public class TestCustomer {

   public static void main(String args[]) {

   Customer customer1 = new Customer(3000, 20, 5);
   Customer customer2 = new Customer(5000, 15, 7);
   Customer customer3 = new Customer(5000, 20, 5);
   Customer customer4 = new Customer(3000, 3, 5);
   Customer customer5 = new Customer(3000, 3, 8);


   // comparator test

   Customer.WorthComparator worth = new Customer.WorthComparator();
   Customer.LoyaltyComparator loyal = new Customer.LoyaltyComparator();
   Customer.WorthPoliteComparator polite = new Customer.WorthPoliteComparator();

   assert worth.compare(customer1, customer2) == -1;  
   assert worth.compare(customer2, customer3) == 0;  
   assert worth.compare(customer2, customer1) == 1; 

   assert loyal.compare(customer1, customer2) == 1; 
   assert loyal.compare(customer2, customer1) == -1; 
   assert loyal.compare(customer1, customer3) == 0; 

   assert polite.compare(customer3, customer2) == -1; 
   assert polite.compare(customer2, customer3) == 1; 
   assert polite.compare(customer1, customer2) == -1; 
   assert polite.compare(customer2, customer3) == 1; 
   assert polite.compare(customer1, customer4) == 0;

   // priority queue test

   PriorityQueue<Customer> pQueueW = new PriorityQueue<Customer>(worth); 
   PriorityQueue<Customer> pQueueL = new PriorityQueue<Customer>(loyal);
   PriorityQueue<Customer> pQueueP = new PriorityQueue<Customer>(polite); 



   // push -- type T, pass in a val // judgement upon worth

   //PUSH customers for Worth
   pQueueW.push(customer1);
   pQueueW.push(customer2);
   pQueueW.push(customer4);
   assert pQueueW.pop() == customer2;



   //PUSH customers for Loyalty
   pQueueL.push(customer1);
   pQueueL.push(customer2);
   pQueueL.push(customer3);
   assert pQueueL.pop() == customer1;


   //PUSH customers for Polite
   pQueueP.push(customer2);
   pQueueP.push(customer4);
   pQueueP.push(customer5);
   assert pQueueP.pop() == customer2;
   assert pQueueP.pop() == customer5;


   //























   }

   }
```

My Priority Queue class simply extends Queue and uses its push function. I will need to make a method to call to my pop in Queue:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class PriorityQueue<T> extends Queue<T>
{

   Comparator<T> compare;

   public PriorityQueue(Comparator<T> comp)
   {
      compare = comp;
   }


    //@Override
   public void push(T val)
   {
       super.push(val); //right now this is just a normal Queue as it will do what its parent did.
   }
```

My customer class has a constructor to create customers. This is also where I implement my different comparators to create an ordering of customers:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Customer
{

   int netWorth;
   int yearsWithCompany;
   int politeness;


   public Customer(int netWorth,int yearsWithCompany,int politeness)
   {
      this.netWorth = netWorth;
      this.yearsWithCompany = yearsWithCompany;
      this.politeness = politeness;
   }


/**
   compares clients based on thier net worth
*/
   public static class WorthComparator implements Comparator<Customer>
   {




   */
      public int compare(Customer c1, Customer c2)
      {
         int net1 = c1.netWorth;
         int net2 = c2.netWorth;
         if (net1 == net2) {
            return 0;
            }
         else if (net1 < net2) {
            return -1;
            }
         else {
            return 1;
            }
      }

   }


/**
   compares clients based on thier loyalty 
*/
   public static class LoyaltyComparator implements Comparator<Customer>
   {

   /**



   */
      public int compare(Customer c1, Customer c2)
      {

         int years1 = c1.yearsWithCompany;
         int years2 = c2.yearsWithCompany;

         if (years1 == years2) {
            return 0;
            }
         else if (years1 < years2) {
            return -1;
            }
         else {
            return 1;
            }

      }

   }



/**
   compares clients based on thier net worth.
   If there is a tie, politeness is used.
*/
   public static class WorthPoliteComparator implements Comparator<Customer>
   {

   /**

   */
      public int compare(Customer c1, Customer c2)
      {
         if (c1.netWorth == c2.netWorth)
        {
         if (c1.politeness < c2.politeness) {
            return -1;
         }        
         else if (c1.politeness > c2.politeness) {
            return 1;
         }
         else {
            return 0;
            }
         }
        else if (c1.netWorth > c2.netWorth){
         //int politeness = WorthComparator.compare(c1, c2);
         //return politeness;
         return 1;
          }

        else {
         return -1 ;
         }


         }

   }

}
```

My Queue class WAS implemented to function as a regular queue. I am now modifying it so that I can turn it into a Priority Queue. The Queue class is below:
    public class Queue
    {

```
   public class QNode<T> {

      private QNode<T> node;
      private T val;  

      public QNode(QNode<T> node, T val) {
         this.node = node;
         this.val = val;

      }
   }

   protected QNode<T> head;
   protected QNode<T> rear;
   protected QNode<T> temp;




   public Queue()
   {
      head = null;
      rear = null;

         }

   public void push(T val) // T = Customer type -- val is a customer
   {
      // if I wanted to get the contents out of val, which is a customer
      // who has a net worth, years loyal, and politeness
      // how would I access let's say, the netWorth from val?

      // first node created
      if (head == null && rear == null){
         head = new QNode<T>(rear, val);
         rear = head;

      }


   }

   public T pop()
   {
      if (head == null){
         throw new QueueUnderFlowException();
      }

      else if(head == rear) {
        T temp_hold = head.val;
        head = null;
        rear = null;
        return temp_hold;

      }

      else {

         T oldN = head.val;

         this.head = this.head.node;
         return oldN;      
         }
      }

    /**
      returns true if the queue is empty
     */

   public boolean isEmpty()
   {
      if (head == null) {
       return true;
   }
      else {
       return false;
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access methods of generic type in generic class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26555883/access-methods-of-generic-type-in-generic-class)

Comment: I appreciate the reference. I will give it a look. @JulienLopez

Answer (score 2):

If your `Queue` is generic, you can't refer to properties of `Customer` directly. You'll have to make them accessible via some interface/baseclass the `Queue` knows about. Since the `Queue` doesn't really care about the customer's net worth, but about sorting between different customers, there are two classic ways of doing this.

First, you could make the `Queue` handle [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) objects:

```
public class Queue<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    // code...
```

and make the `Customer` comparable by its networth:

```
public class Customer implements Comparable<Customer> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Customer other) {
        return Integer.compare(netWorth, other.netWorth);
    }

    // rest of the code...
}
```

or, if you don't want to impose this natural ordering on the `Customer` class, the `Queue` class can take a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), such as `Comparator.comparingInt(Customer::getNetWorth())` when its constructed.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion. I have updated my code to show more of what is going on. I have to some extent misinformed you, and I apologize.